# Why is my shell script cutting off the first number in my output?

Tags: bash, unix

Here is my script:

```
mean1=$4.77953
echo "Mean: $mean1"
```

But instead of printing `Mean: 4.77953` it prints `Mean: .77953`. What is causing this?

Comment: how are you running your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put $ by accident in front of 4

try

```
mean1=4.77953
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash thinks `$4` is a variable (the 4th [argument](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html#EX17) passed to your script) in your *mean1* declaration and this one is not set.

Answer (score 1):

Bash is [expanding](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) `$4` to the fourth argument of your script. You should single quote your string in order to avoid the expansion.

```
mean1='$4.77953'
```